# Give labels in Qt Forms

Tags: qt4

How can I set a label in Qt Ui forms.

Answer (score 1):

Just click in the mainwindow.ui. Then in the Display widget label is present drag the label and placed it on the mainwindow.ui. Using the properties and change label according to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [QLabel](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qlabel.html) class. In Qt Creator you will find it in the display widgets.